# How to add characters in the middle of a word in an arraylist in java?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, replace

I'm practicing `ArrayList`'s. I'm trying to make it so that every time `is` is in the ArrayList, it is then followed with `not`. For instance `[is sky, is, this is blue, is is, is not]` after running through the method comes out as `[is not sky, is not, this is not blue, is not is not, is not not]`. However, with my code right now it does not change. I am new to Java, so I would really appreciate any pointers!

```java
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add("is sky");
        list.add("is");
        list.add("this is blue");
        list.add("is is");
        list.add("is not");

        System.out.println(replace(list));
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> replace(ArrayList<String> list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.subList(i, i + 1).equals("is")) {
                list.add(i + 1, " not");
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First solve the simplest case. Forget the list for a moment and do the substitution with just one `String`.

```
String replaceOne(String original) {
    return original.replace("is", "is not");
}
```

Test this method.

```
String replaced = replaceOne("sky is");
```

The test passes if this `replaced` variable is equal to `sky is not`.

Once you've guaranteed that, move on to the general case, with a list.

```
void replaceMany(ArrayList<String> original) {
    for (int i = 0; i < original.size(); i++) {
        original.set(i, replaceOne(original.get(i)));
    }
}
```

Note that if you're running this inside a static method, the above methods need to be static (i.e. `static void`, `static String`).

With Java 8 you could also solve this problem differently. Instead of using the `set` method on the array list, you could use lambdas and a collector to get a modified list (preserve the original and get another list with the modified strings). Something like:

```
List<String> replaced = original.stream()
    .map(s -> replaceOne(s))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

With *Java 9*, you can simplify your code as follows:

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = List.of(
                "is sky", "is", "this is blue", "is is", "is not");

        System.out.println(replace(list));
    }
    public static List<String> replace(List<String> list) {
        return list.stream()
                .map(str -> str.replace("is", "is not"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[is not sky, is not, this not is not blue, is not is not, is not not]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your if statement is always false. Method subList returns list that you compare with string in line:

```
list.subList(i, i+1).equals("is")
```